# How to set a string as dynamic attributes in a JSX element

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to add a string of text to attributes of JSX element. Look at the example below where variable  `otherAttributes` is a sting. Actually in my case it's a variable that's coming from CMS and I want to add it as attributes.

```html
const otherAttributes = 'target="_blank" rel="follow"';
<a href={href || ''} class="inline-block px-4 py-2 rounded-full" {...otherAttributes}>{text}</a>
```

I get output as

```html
<a 0="&quot;" 1="t" 2="a" 3="r" 4="g" 5="e" 6="t" 7="=" 8="\" 9="&quot;" 10="_" 11="b" 12="l" 13="a" 14="n" 15="k" 16="\" 17="&quot;" 18="&quot;" href="" class="inline-block px-4 py-2 rounded-full" >See more</a>
```

Comment: Convert `otherAttributes` to an object before spreading

Comment: That's why I asked how to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert the string to an object, so you can spread the key/values to your child component

An example, were I use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create the object.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const otherAttributes = 'target="_blank" rel="follow"';
    const attributesAsObj = otherAttributes.split(' ').reduce((p, c) => {
        const [ key, value ] = c.split('=');
        return { ...p, [key]: JSON.parse(value) };
    }, {});
    
    return <Child {...attributesAsObj} />;
}

const Child = (props) => {
    console.log('Child props', props);
    return <em>{'Child'}</em>;
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
**Note** that the conversion to an object might fail for complex cases like where the value contains another `=` or space.

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
import React from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const otherAttributes = {
    target: '_blank',
    rel: 'follow'
  };
  const href = '';
  const text = "hello";
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <a href={href || ''} className="inline-block px-4 py-2 rounded-full" {...otherAttributes}>{text}</a>
    </div>
  );
}

// Log to console
console.log('Hello console')
```

Comment: You;re explicitly made an array which is not possible in my case because it's cming from the CMS and user can set anything in the text field. I can expect any html attribute